# Create factor in a data frame that minimizes correlation with other variables in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, orthogonal, experimental-design

I am trying to create a **factor variable with 3 levels** and add it to an existing `data frame` with the condition that this **new factor is as uncorrelated as possible** with the the variables in the `data frame`.

Is there an R function that can help me accomplish this?

To elaborate, I have an existing experimental design and I want to augment it with this new factor variable with 3 levels with the condition that it is orthogonal as possible to the existing design.

Typically, I use the `AlgDesign` to create d-optimal designs using the `optFederov()` function, but it is not clear to me if I can coerce the functions in that package to accomplish what I want.